Perpendicular Relation concerning the Incenter of a Triangle
Problem:

Let $I$ be the incenter of triangle $ABC$. Let $D,E,F$ be the points of tangency of circle $I$ with sides $BC,AC,AB$, respectively. Suppose lines $EF$ and $BC$ meet at $K$. Prove that $AD \perp KI$.

I came across this conjecture while solving an olympiad geometry problem, but I am having troubles proving it. I tried but failed to show that $AD$ passes through the other point of tangency from $K$ to circle $I$; thus I am hoping to get some hints regarding how I could approach these kind of perpendicular-proof problems. Thank you!


For the convenience of readers, when asking a geometry question, it's nice to include a picture with the post, I added one, replace it if you wish.

Solving such exercises using barycentric calculation is trivial, provided you have the right calculation tools. Confining such exercises to “Olympics exercises” therefore seems regrettable to me. What about ETC ( https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html )!

Here is a solution using only geometric constructions, and mainly inversion properties.

The picture to follow the steps is:



Let $*$ be the inversion with center $A$ which invariates the points $E,F$.
Let $\mathcal I$ be for short time the circle $\mathcal I=\odot(DEF)$. Which is its image $\mathcal I^*$ through this inversion? It is also a circle, it passes through $E^*=E$ and $F^*=F$, and is tangent to the lines $AE,AF$ also invariated by inversion, so $\mathcal I$ is kept in place as a set.
The point $D^*\ne D$ is thus the second intersection of the line $AD$ with this circle $\mathcal I=\odot(DEF)$.
Let $I^*$ be the image of $I$, it is $I^*=AI\cap EF$.
The line $EF$ and the circle $\mathcal C=\odot(AEIF)$ are mapped in each other. Since $K\in EF$ its image $K^*$ is a point on this circle.
The pair $I,K$ is mapped by inversion onto $I^*,K^*$, so these four points are on a circle. So $\widehat {IK^*K} = \widehat {II^*K} = 90^\circ$, so $K^*$ is the projection of $I$ on $AK$.
The pair $D,K$ is mapped to the pair $D^*,K^*$, so these four points are on a circle. The quadrilateral $IDKK^*$ is also cyclic because of the right angles in $D,K^*$. So all the points $I,D,D^*,K,K^*$ (and $I^*$) are on a circle. Its center is on $IK$ because of the right angle in $D$.
From $ID=ID^*$ we conclude that $IK\perp DD^*$.

$\square$

Bonus:
With this insight many other properties can be shown. For instance the fact that the circle $(BDCK)^*=AD^*K^*$ is tangent in $D^*$ to $DED^*F$, and has its center is in the same on $ID^*$ and on the perpendicular bisector of $AK^*$, a line parallel to $IK^*$. Also, the projection $P$ of $A$ onto the opposite side $BC$ transforms into a point $P^*$ which is on the height $AP$, on the line $IK^*$, and on the circle $(BDPCK)^K$. Also, $AD$, $EF$, $IK^*$ are concurrent.

Consider the diagram below. Let $S$ be the intersection of $AD$ and $IK$. Assume $\angle EIS=I_1$, $\angle SID=I_2$, $\angle EAS=\angle EAD=A_1$, and $IE=ID=r$. Then, we only need to show that $I_1=A_1$ $(why?)$.
By using the law of sine in the appropriate triangles and some angle chasing, we get:
$$\frac{\sin (\angle C+I_1)}{\sin I_1}=\frac{\sin (180^{\circ}-\angle C-I_1)}{\sin I_1}=\frac{\sin I_2}{\sin I_1}\\=\frac{\frac{DK}{IK}}{\sin \angle IEK \times \frac{EK}{IK}}=\frac{\frac{DK}{IK}}{\sin (90^{\circ}+90^{\circ}-\frac{\angle A}{2}) \times \frac{EK}{IK}}\\=\frac{DK}{EK} \times \frac{1}{\sin \frac{\angle A}{2}}= \frac{\sin \angle DEK}{\sin \angle EDK}\times \frac{1}{\sin \frac{\angle A}{2}}\\=\frac{\sin (\frac{\angle A+\angle C}{2})}{\cos \frac{\angle C}{2}}\times \frac{1}{\sin \frac{\angle A}{2}}\\=1+\cot\frac{\angle A}{2} \tan \frac{\angle C}{2}.$$

On the other hand,
$$\frac{\sin (\angle C+A_1)}{\sin A_1}=\frac{\sin (180^{\circ}-\angle C-A_1)}{\sin A_1}=\frac{AC}{DC}=\frac{AE+EC}{DC}\\=1+\frac{\frac{AE}{r}}{\frac{DC}{r}}=1+\frac{\cot\frac{\angle A}{2}}{\cot\frac{\angle C}{2}}\\=1+\cot\frac{\angle A}{2} \tan \frac{\angle C}{2}.$$
Thus, we have:
$$\frac{\sin (\angle C+I_1)}{\sin I_1}=\frac{\sin (\angle C+A_1)}{\sin A_1} \implies A_1=I_1 (why?).$$
We are done.

With appropriate tools, this exercice is trivial. Using Conway triangle notation and recalling that $I\simeq a:b:c$, we easily obtain using barycentric calculus with $$A\simeq 1:0:0,\,B\simeq0:1:0,\, C\simeq0:0:1$$
that $$D\simeq 0:ab+S_C:ac+S_B\text{ (et circularly)}$$
It is then trivial to obtain via formal calculation software that $$\vec{AD}\cdot \vec{KI}=0.\square$$

I attach below the sagemath program which gives me this result:

var('a b c')
                              
def perpendiculaire(droite,point,pyth,Linf):
  inf=droite.cross_product(Linf)
  droiteortho=pyth*inf 
  orthopoint=droiteortho.cross_product(Linf)
  perp=orthopoint.cross_product(point)  
  return perp

def vecteur(X,Y) :
    vec=vector([Y[0]/(Y[0]+Y[1]+Y[2])-X[0]/(X[0]+X[1]+X[2]),Y[1]/(Y[0]+Y[1]+Y[2])-X[1]/(X[0]+X[1]+X[2]),Y[2]/(Y[0]+Y[1]+Y[2])-X[2]/(X[0]+X[1]+X[2])])
    return vec

A=vector([1,0,0])
B=vector([0,1,0])
C=vector([0,0,1])
Linf=vector([1,1,1])

pyth=1/2*matrix([[0,-c^2,-b^2],[-c^2,0,-a^2],[-b^2,-a^2,0]])
AB=A.cross_product(B)
BC=B.cross_product(C)
CA=C.cross_product(A)
I=vector([a,b,c])

D=perpendiculaire(BC,I,pyth,Linf).cross_product(BC)
print (D)
E=perpendiculaire(AB,I,pyth,Linf).cross_product(AB)
F=perpendiculaire(CA,I,pyth,Linf).cross_product(CA)
l=E.cross_product(F)
K=l.cross_product(BC)
nul=vecteur(K,I)*pyth*vecteur(A,D)
print (E)
print (F)
print(factor(nul))

